# Expand Raid 10 set on MegaRAID LSI 9261-8i

Tags: raid, raid10, megacli

I have an existing Raid 10 drive with 8 drives. 4 in each span.  I can't figure out how to expand the set by adding two more drives, one to each span.  I'm using the MegaCLI command line tool.

I would like to keep the data on the drives if possible.   I've read the MegaCLI manual and searched several places with no luck.

Comment: A side note, I think you should set up 4 mirrors and strip those mirrors instead for RAID 10, but I'm also interested in knowing how to do this